# How could I make node-cron run only once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, node-cron

I want to console log "hi" in 10 minutes but only once. How could I achieve this with node-cron?

Tried to use some others but they failed to do the job.

Comment: "*Tried to use some others but they failed to do the job.*" In the future, you should include your attempt(s) in the body of your question in accordance with the guidelines on creating a [mre], as well as [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`node-cron` supports passing a `Date` object to fire an event at a specific date and time. From [`node-cron`'s `README.md`](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron/blob/master/README.md):

> Additionally, this library goes beyond the basic cron syntax and allows you to supply a Date object. This will be used as the trigger for your callback.

> ##### API
>
> [...]
>
> - `CronJob`
>
>   - `constructor(cronTime, onTick, onComplete, start, timezone, context, runOnInit, utcOffset, unrefTimeout)`
>
>     - `cronTime` - [REQUIRED] - The time to fire off your job. This can be in the form of cron syntax or a JS Date object.
>
> [...]

In short, create a `Date()` object that represents the time 10 minutes from execution:

```
const cron = require('node-cron');

const datetime = new Date();
const adjustedDatetime = datetime.setMinutes(datetime.setMinutes() + 10); 
const eventDatetimeObject = new Date(adjustedDatetime);

cron.schedule(eventDatetimeObject, () => console.log("hi"));
```